# Synchronization: Wake up a thread when all other threads have left

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, mutex, semaphore, monitor

Here's the scenario:
When my application is shutting down I wish to start a disposing thread but it must sleep straight away. I want all the running threads enter a cleanup section. Once all of those threads have finished their job and left the section, I want the disposing section wake up and finaliaze the shut down process.

Which synchronization mechanism should I use, Mutex, Monitor, or Semaphore? and How?

Thanks.

Comment: Semaphore or CountdownLatch

Comment: Is there any way, at all, that you can avoid or design away the need for this effort, eg. by cleaning up at startup instead of shutdown?